# Windows Update downloaded and installed update's despite being set to manual

Tags: windows-update

I have a windows 2016 datacenter server.

Using Sconfig, Windows Update Settings were set to Manual (some time ago)

If I check the registry HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate, the only entry in there is in \Au, which is NoAutoUpdate = 1

So from my understanding, the server is correctly configured to manual, and it should not be downloading or installing Windows Updates, unless triggered by a user.

Checking the Event Log Applications and Services > Microsoft > Windows > Windows UpdateClient > Operational, I can see that Windows Updates has successfully found updates, which have been downloading, even though this was not triggered by a user.

If I go into Control Panel > Security and Maintenance > Reliability Monitor, for the 6th Feb, it tells me that it has successfully installed 4 updates

I've also looked over the log produced, by running powershell command Get-WindowsUpdateLog, and have found the log entry where Windows Update Agent is initialised, but I cannot find anything indicating what initialized it...
2020/02/06 03:10:30.0626515 928   4336  Agent      Initializing Windows Update Agent

Since this server is set to Manual only, I need to find and understand what has triggered the Orchestra to scan and download updates, and then install them.

Has anyone got any tips on where I should next check?

**Additional Information from questions asked in this post**

The server did not reboot after installing the update, but has been marked as PendingReboot.
This has been confirmed by checking registry: HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired
Which now contains 2 entries:

70f66ef9-c066-4ef6-aa4e-8945086be6a4 = 1

f9f38f3b-acbb-47ae-bdcb-858d1c9ade4e = 1

Comment: Hi, does a reboot was done after the registry key NoAutoUpdate was set ?

Comment: It did not reboot, but it has been marked as pending reboot, which I confirmed by checking if there was entries in the registry HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired

Comment: Ok, I asked, as the registry settings is read when the windows update service start, so I assume the settings wasnt respected as the process was already started

Comment: As mentioned, this server has been set to manual for some time (im talking over half a year), so yes I agree that something is not respecting this setting, but I dont know how to identify what it is not respecting it, or why. Any ideas?

Comment: I would have a look in gpedit at *Comp Configuration > Admin Templates > Windows Components > Windows Updates > Configure Automatic Updates* to see what's configured there. (Mine is set to 2 and doesn't seem to do anything until I go in to do it)

Comment: In GPEdit, all the settings show as not configured, because it was configured via Sconfig, not group policys. It should be noted this Server is not domain joined